# How to programmatically validate Json string against a Json schema in Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I want to validate *the format and structure* of a JSON object against its JSON schema using Java. Where can I begin?

Comment: you can use Jackson lib to help in this.

Comment: You've online tools to validate this.
I usually use http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/
If you need to validate it using Java code then this should help.
http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/

Comment: I would recommend reading this article with provided solutions: https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for an online tool then you can try 
[jsonschemalint-online-validator](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/)

If you need to validate it using Java code then [validate-json-against-schema-in-java](http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/) should help. It provides a step by step approach, along with sample code for reference.

Comment: the validate-json-against-schema-in-java link is broken

Comment: @JoãoMatos Seems to be working. I just opened it.